# Displaying data in jsp using struts and hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, jsp, struts2

i am stuck in a project with a problem. The problem is simple but i am not aware of the solution. Here is my problem:

I have an Employee class mapped with Hibernate, Employee Table.

```
Class Employee
  int empId;
  int empName;
```

Then i have a Assignment class mapped with Hibernate, Assignment Table. For each employee, i have a record in my Assignment class along with an employee's Supervisor ID. The supervisor is also defined in the Employee class.

```
Class Assignment
 int empId;
 int supervisorId; //empId of the Supervisor in the Employee Table.
```

Now, in my action class, i generated an iterator first having an object of the Assignment Class and i am displaying it in my jsp like below:

```
<s:iterator value="assignmentList">
   <s:property value="empId"/>
   <s:property value="supervisorId"/>
   //Now here i want to display the empName of both the Employee and Supervisor.
   //How can i pass the <s:property value="empId"/> and <s:property value="supervisorId"/> values to an action to get the Employee Class Objects so that i can display the employee names.
```

I think its a simple problem of joining two tables, but don't know, how to implement it in struts2. Please help.

**EDIT**

Here is my modified code

Employee Class

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name="usertable")
   public class User implements java.io.Serializable{

   private int id;
  private String empName;
  private String firstName;
  private Assignment assignment;

 public Employee(){
 }

@Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    @Column(name="empname")
    public String getEmpname() {
        return empName;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "usertable", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Assignment getAssignment() {
        return assignment;
    }

    public void setAssignment(Assignment assignment) {
        this.assignment = assignment;
    }
}
```

Assignment Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="assignment")
public class Assignment implements java.io.Serializable{

private int id;
private Employee employee;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
public Employee getEmployee() {
    return employee;
}
public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
    this.employee = employee;
}

}
```

Save method in Action class

```
SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
Session session = sf.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
      Employee emp=new Employee();
  Assignment assgn =new Assignment();
  emp.setAssignment(assgn);
  assgn.setEmployee(emp);
  session.save(assgn);
  session.save(emp);

  session.getTransaction().commit();
  session.close();
```

My Util class:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure()
                .buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

}

And when i run the save method in my action class i am getting this exception:

```
Struts has detected an unhandled exception:

Messages:   
File:   org/hibernate/cfg/OneToOneSecondPass.java
Line number:    135

java.lang.NullPointerException
org.hibernate.cfg.OneToOneSecondPass.doSecondPass(OneToOneSecondPass.java:135)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1163)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:296)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1319)
common.HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:14)
backEnd.admin.saveemployee(admin.java:137)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

Now how to solve this? I am using Hibernate annotation Version 3.2.1. Please help.

Comment: Could you change your entities? So your `Assignment` class holds reference of `Employee`.

Comment: Tried this. Getting an exception, please have a look.

Comment: The tittle of this question makes no sense.

Comment: Changed the title. Now how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have one-to-one ( or one-to-many depending on your model) mapping configured here.  Since you mentioned that you have an assignment record against each employee so it means that  Employee bean should have a reference to its related assignment bean.

I assume you are using annotation configuration in hibernate so some minor changes in your Employee class should do the trick

```
//Injecting the assignment bean inside the employee bean    
private Assignement employeeAssignement;

//Lazy type fetching means to get the assignemnt tuple only when it is needed
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "Employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Assignment getEmployeeAssignment() {
    return this.employeeAssignement;
}

public void setEmployeeAssignement(EmployeeAssignement employeeAssignement) {
    this.employeeAssignement = employeeAssignement;
}
```

Also its good practice to keep a separate bean for displaying purpose from your entity beans that are mapped with the database.
Make a bean , say EmployeeDetailBean and specify the fields that you want to display on the JSP.

```
public class EmployeeDetailBean{
 //The fields you want to display on the JSP
 ......
 //valid getter/setter
}
```

Set these fields when your action class is called, create getter/setters for this bean and  iterate over this bean once your JSP is being called just like you are iterating over the other bean mentioned in your post.

Comment: Thanks, i will try this and let you know how it goes. The good practice you mentioned means, i will be keeping a separate Bean for all Entity beans for displaying purpose. These separate beans won't be mapped to database, Right? How does this improves the design and performance. I am asking as i am new in these kinds of designs.Thanks

Comment: The separate beans will be used only for displaying purposes and will not be mapped with databases. I can't really say about performance, but it offers a good separation between the data layer and the view layer. The data bean ( mapped with the DB ) should only contain the fields as they are in the table, while on the other hand you can change the fields in the display bean as per your requirements as to how you want to display on page. Like e.g data bean may contain fields as firstName and lastName while in display bean you can merge them into a single field UserName=firstName+lastName.